# req.FormValue not mapping req.body values

Tags: rest, go, post

I'm trying to pick out a value in the request.body but I keep getting an empty string.
The Form map is also coming up as empty.
What am I doing wrong?

```
package user

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "../../types"
)

func PostTest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    r.ParseForm()

    x := r.FormValue("name")
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

The body of the post request:

```
{
    "name":"Tom",
    "age":25
}
```

Comment: How is PostTest called?

Comment: `ParseForm` will parse url encoded forms. You're sending json. You have to read the request body and unmarshal it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because the request body is not valid form data, but a blob of JSON data. You will need to parse it before being able to extract the name, e.g.:

```
type data struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

func PostTest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var d data
    json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&d) // Error handling omitted.
    fmt.Println(d.Name)
}
```

Here's a [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/mgpLvht_iHj) demonstrating this. I have omitted error handling for brevity.